# How to get past the section with revolving lines of dots in Transition?

Tags: bit-trip-beat

So I got myself bit.trip beat. And I started playing through the first song, Transition. I had no particular problem, till I got here:

I failed hard and fast here, not once but three times in a row. How are you supposed to hit those?

Comment: Kind of a minor tip, but make sure that you *disable* vsync for this game. Made a huge difference for me.

Comment: +1.  I just bought the game too (discounted on Steam) and failed at exactly this point as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the small groups of 3 dots, you'll want to line yourself up so you're perfectly in the middle of them. By the time they are finished rotating, they'll be lined up to hit your paddle.

For the longer ones, which you are having the most trouble with, what you'll have to do is move your paddle so it is lined up to hit the point that is angled closest to you. I've circled which block you'll want to aim for in the picture below. Then you should quickly move your paddle in the direction of the rest of the block.

[image: Aim for this spot]

I tried to take successive screenshots of this occurring, but it's really hard to because of the slight delay. Here's a shot of me in the middle of doing this with the longer block lines. Again, I aimed for the block that was coming in closest to me (the circled one) then moved my paddle quickly in the direction of the rest of the line. I marked where you should aim to hit the incoming lines, assuming they wouldn't rotate more before they got to you (which they likely would, but just to be clear). I marked the rows I've already hit that are moving away from me with blue arrows.

[image: Boop boop boop!]

It might take some practice, but you should be able to stay out of the Nether once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

For the small groups of 3 dots, the rotation is just there to throw you off. When they reach your paddle, they are *always* lined up vertically. Center your paddle on the middle dot and you'll reflect all three.

Comment: This is only kinda sorta true... for most of those instead you have to slowly move your mouse in the direction opposite to the one they approach from.

Comment: That's only true for the very small groups of three shown at the top. The longer ones require you to move along the line, making it "turn into" your paddle. Hard to describe (and hard to do right).

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I guess my answer only applies to the groups of 3.